# Joined attributes not available in Feature Service

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, feature-service

I have a joined feature class (`PROPERTY`) and table (`OG_LEASE`). When I publish this as part of a map service and feature service, attributes are only available in the map service.

Map service fields:

```
PROPERTY.OBJECTID
PROPERTY.TAX_MAP_NUMBER
PROPERTY.OWNER
OG_LEASE.OBJECTID
OG_LEASE.COUNTY
OG_LEASE.TERM
(etc.)
```

Feature service fields:

```
OBJECTID
```

How can I ensure that the feature service has all the joined attributes (as well as the original feature class attributes!) published? The only warning that came up when publishing was that the join field didn't have an attribute index.

(I did look at [Problems displaying joined attribute data through ArcGIS Server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58545/problems-displaying-joined-attribute-data-through-arcgis-server) but it's not directly related to my question -- both my feature class and table are in the same ArcSDE database. I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting that you didn't get a warning `24040: Layer has an in-memory join or relate`. This is because your map layer has an associated join (or relate) that was created in the map document using the layer properties dialog box. Joined and related attributes will not be accessible through the feature service.

From the [help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/publish-map-services/24040-layer-has-an-in-memory-join-or-relate.htm):

> Feature services allow queries on related data. **For example, a
>   published map document can have layers and tables that are related
>   through geodatabase relationship classes**. In this case, the feature
>   service allows queries on a layer to return objects from the related
>   layer or table. **Note that to support queries that return related
>   objects, both the table and the layer involved in the relationship
>   class must be in the published map document.** If either the origin
>   and/or destination layer or table is not included in the map document,
>   the relationship is ignored by the feature service.

Either create a view in the geodatabase that will have a OG_LEASE table fields joined or create a relationship class.